# Parameters control in jenkins using pipelines as code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

**Can we write like this in pipeline script?. Need to populate the string by choice parameter.**  I am new to Jenkins world.

```
parameters { choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: ['FirstName', 'LastName'], description: 'Pick something') }        

script {
if (${CHOICE} == "FirstName")
{
    parameters { string(name: 'FirstName', defaultValue: '', description: 'This is FirstName')}
}
else
{
    parameters { string(name: 'LastName', defaultValue: '', description: 'This is LastName') }
}
}
```

**Is there any other way to do it inside the jenkins? Any plugin which can help!**

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

If what you want is interactivity — when you make a choice in the dropdown box, the contents of another parameter changes based on your choice — then ActiveChoice plugin can help you with that.

If you want to define different params as depending on your choice of the first one, then it's not possible. Jenkins needs to fully parse your Jenkinsfile (parameters and all) in order to present you with the parameters screen, but you seem to want to define your parameters based on the results of the presentation. This is a kind of a chicken and egg problem here.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comments. I have solved the issue using ActiveChoice plugni.